# ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have added an `IF` clause to my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_path_set(IN pathset_id_in character,OUT id character,OUT  pathset_id character,OUT utility double precision)
RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "A" WHERE "ID" = $1)  THEN 
        SELECT "ID", "PATHSET_ID", "UTILITY"
        FROM "B"
        where "PATHSET_ID" = $1;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$

  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

And it throws an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 8:  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "A" ...
```

Am I missing something?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the language is SQL, it needs to be a regular query, so convert the logic to plain SQL by moving the `IF` condition inside the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT "ID", "PATHSET_ID", "UTILITY"
FROM "B"
WHERE "PATHSET_ID" = $1
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "A" WHERE "ID" = $1)
```

Comment: thanks. 2 questions: 1- if I just change the language, will the `IF EXIST` query work? what language do I have to use? 2- and when I made it work, which one of the two solutions will be 'faster'?

Comment: Use language `plpgsql` to use "flow control statements" (of which "IF" is one). I would leave it like this - it's easier to understand and test - you can paste it into an SQL query tool. performance difference is unlikely to be much different and could even be worse with plsql